# How to force System.Text.Json.JsonElement.GetProperty to search for properties using case-insensitive method?

Tags: c#, .net, system.text.json

Here's my JSON:

```
{
    firstName: 'Somebody',
    lastName: 'Else'
}
```

And I deserialize it into `JsonElement` using these options:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions {
                    WriteIndented = true,
                    PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,
                    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase
                };
```

But then I want to search for properties, it becomes **case-sensitive**.

```
element.GetProperty("FirstName") // this returns null
element.GetProperty("firstName") // this returns 'Somebody'
```

How can I force `GetProperty` method to become case-insensitive?

Answer (score 4):

As per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-customize-properties?pivots=dotnet-6-0#use-a-custom-json-property-naming-policy) you should be able to create `JsonNamingPolicy` like this one which should do the job:

```cs
using System.Text.Json;

namespace SystemTextJsonSamples
{
    public class LowerCaseNamingPolicy : JsonNamingPolicy
    {
        public override string ConvertName(string name) =>
            name.ToLower();
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Then you can use it by changing your options configuration to this:

```cs
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions {
    WriteIndented = true,
    PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,
    PropertyNamingPolicy = new LowerCaseNamingPolicy()
};
```

Edit2:

then you can search for the property the following way:

```cs
element.GetProperty("FirstName".ToLower())
element.GetProperty("firstName".ToLower())
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use `System.Text.json.JsonNode` with a `JsonNodeOptions`:

```
var jsonNode = JsonNode.Parse(
    "jsonStr", 
    new JsonNodeOptions {PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true});

jsonNode["FirstName"].ToString(); // this returns 'Somebody'
jsonNode["firStNamE"].ToString(); // this returns 'Somebody'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write an extension method for this:

```
static class JEelementExtensions
{
    public static object GetPropertyCaseInsensitive(this JsonElement element, string propertyName)
    {
        foreach (var property in element.EnumerateObject().OfType<JsonProperty>())
        {
            if (property.Name.Equals(propertyName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) return property.Value;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And here is the same extension method as a one-liner. This version throws an exception if the property doesnt exist:

```
public static object GetPropertyCaseInsensitive(this JsonElement element, string propertyName) => element
    .EnumerateObject().First(p => p.Name.Equals(propertyName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).Value;
```

Usage:

```
    var prop1 = element.GetPropertyCaseInsensitive("firstName");// this returns 'Somebody'
    var prop2 = element.GetPropertyCaseInsensitive("FirstName");// this returns 'Somebody'
    var prop3 = element.GetPropertyCaseInsensitive("fIrStNAmE");// this returns 'Somebody'
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need any options, if you use LINQ to JSON  of  NewtonSoft.Jason

Try this code , assuming jObject = JObject.Parse(json). This code was tested in Visual Studio using your json

```
 var firstName= jObject.Properties().First(i=>i.Name.ToLower()=="firstname").Value;
```

using this algoritm you can use not only ==, but Contains, StartWith, EndsEith.

```
var firstName= jObject.Properties().FirstOrDefault(i=> i.Name.ToLower()
.Contains("first")).Value;
```

Comment: I like this approach due to its simplicity

Comment: @NigelBess Thank you! And you can use all Linq functions for search as well.

Comment: Actually, `JsonElement` doesnt have the method `Properties()` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonelement?view=net-6.0

Comment: @NigelBess What JsonElement has to do with  PO json? We are talking how to get a value by name , not  about JsonElement.

Comment: Ops question is about JsonElement